# Reference becomes dangling in expression template

Tags: c++, templates, reference

I wrote an expression template code, but I had an error.
And the following is just a minimal reproducible example.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename Derived>
class VecExp {
 public:
  double operator[](int i) const {return static_cast<Derived const&>(*this)[i];}
};

template<int n>
class Vector : public VecExp<Vector<n>> {
 public:

  template<int m>
  Vector(const double(&arr)[m]) {
    static_assert(m==n, "");
    for(int i=0; i<m; ++i) data[i] = arr[i];
  }

  template<typename E>
  Vector(const VecExp<E>& exp) {
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i) data[i] = exp[i];
  }

  double operator[](int i) const {std::cout<<this<<std::endl; return data[i];}
  double& operator[](int i) {return data[i];}
  double data[n];
};

template<typename E1, typename E2>
class VectorSum : public VecExp<VectorSum<E1, E2>>{
  E1 const& lhs;
  E2 const& rhs;
 public:

  VectorSum(E1 const& lhs, E2 const& rhs) : lhs(lhs), rhs(rhs) {
//    std::cout << &(this->lhs) << ", " << &(this->rhs) << std::endl;
  }

  double operator[](int i) const {return lhs[i] + rhs[i];}
};

template<typename E1, typename E2>
VectorSum<E1, E2>
operator + (VecExp<E1> const& lhs, VecExp<E2> const& rhs) {
  return VectorSum<E1, E2>(*static_cast<const E1*>(&lhs), *static_cast<const E2*>(&rhs));
}

int main() {
  Vector<16> v({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16});
  std::cout << &v << std::endl;
  const auto sum = v + v + v + v;
  Vector<16> v2 = sum; // error at here

  std::cout << sum[0] << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

When I try to use `VectorSum<...>`(`sum` in `main()`) that adds more than 3 `Vector`s, the following error happens in a release build.

```
Exception 0xc0000005 encountered at address 0x7ff76f8a1189: Access violation reading location 0x00000000
```

So I attached the pointer printer like above, and then it says

```
00000067C1EFF920
0000000000000000

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

If I attach more printers(i.e: in `operator +` or `VecSum` ctor, ...), then suddenly everything works fine.
Can anyone please tell me why is this error happening?

Used CLion on Windows, Visual Studio community 2019 installed.
[image: toolchain]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`v + v` is an expression of type `VectorSum<Vector<16>, Vector<16>>`.

`v + v + v` is an expression of type `VectorSum<VectorSum<Vector<16>, Vector<16>>, Vector<16>>`, where the type for the first template parameter is significant:

```
   VectorSum<VectorSum<Vector<16>, Vector<16>>, Vector<16>>
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ (B)
// ^^^^^^^^^ (A)
```

The object associated with this specialization, `A`, stores a const reference of type `B const&`, but once the expression `v + v + v` expires so does the lifetime of the sub-expression `v + v`, meaning you are storing a dangling reference in the expression object `(A)` (as the data member `lhs`).

The reason you do not see this problem when just storing the expression template for the expression `v + v` is that both the `lhs` and `rhs` data members of the associated specialization object refers to the object `v` whose lifetime extends to the end of `main()`.

Finally, be careful when storing expression templates in intermediate variables using placeholder types such as `auto`, as it will 1) be likely to yield lifetime issues such as the one above, and 2) is likely to be unexpected to the casual reader, as one could expect (compare with `std::vector<bool>::operator[]`)) `auto = v + v` to result in `decltype(v)` (namely a `Vector<16>`) rather than a proxy type that should for all means be hidden from the client.

Comment: After searching for how to achieve it, absl library gave me the answer. It checks `E1` and `E2`'s type and decide `lhs` and `rhs` type to be reference or not. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @김선달 absl/Titus Winters commonly has a good advice or two when it comes to designing library API:s! Happy to help.